# class="alert hide" does not work. so it is displayed all the time

Tags: javascript, hide, alert, hidden

As the title says I have an alert div, It is a login page where I want to client validate the input fields. So the alert will be shown in case of invalid input usrname/password.

I updated the code according to Gabriler'ssolution. 
The form is a simple login page where I use data annotation to validate the user input, therefor I want to hid the alert on page load. it is my bad I was not clear from the start.
I changed the code to match the suggested solution, but I still not reaching the desired results.

Bellow is the model class:

```
      [DataType(DataType.Text)]
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "password please")]
      public string test { get; set; }


    [MaxLength(10), MinLength(8, ErrorMessage = "check the length")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "missing name")]
    public string test2{ get; set; }
```

and the submit button is below:

```
  <button class="button button-primary button-active" id="danger" 
   type="submit">Login</button>
```

In the CSHTML file, I do the following:

```
          </label>
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name, new { 
          htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-input"
         Type="HtmlInputFile", 
          id="name" , value=""} })
                        <br>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.test, 
                        "", new { @class = "alert alert-error" })
```

My Javascript method look like below: EDITED

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
     myTest();
  });

  var myTest = function () {

    var val1 = $("test").value;
    var val3 = $("test3").value;

    if (val1 !== '' || val3 !=='') {    

      $('input[type="submit"]').$('.alert.alert-error').hide();       
      else {
             $('input[type="submit"]').$('.alert.alert-error').show();
          } 
 }
```

Comment: You're mixing jQuery and DOM methods, have you took a look at the DevConsole?

Comment: Would you please explain what you mean? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: press f12 in the browser and check what error is shown in console

Comment: Notice, that the element `<div class="alert alert-error">` has two separate classes, `alert` and `alert-error`. You can read how selectors actually work at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors). Apparently you haven't hit F12 yet ...

Answer (score 1):

Lets see

1. You have multiple `class` attributes on the `div`. Combine them to one attribute
2. You are mixing, in a wrong way, jquery and native methods. So no `.document` or `getElementsByClassName` after `$(...)`
3. `getElementsByClassName` returns a nodelist so you will have to extract an element before running methods on it (*or loop if you want to run something for all found nodes*).
4. when trying to find a node with jquery you need to use CSS selectors. So `test`, `test2` and `test3` are wrong and should probably be `#test` or `.test` depending if they are ids or classes
5. `.value` is the way to access the value of an input if you have a reference to the DOM element. When going through jQuery you need to use `.val()`

not sure what `$(':input[type="submit"]')` is supposed to do.

---

**update**

for 1 you need to use one attribute not one class per attribute.

```
<div 
class="alert alert-error alert-body alert-heading alert-text" 
role="alert" 
aria-label="blabla...">
</div>
```

About the script you most likely want something like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  validate();
  $('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
    if (!validate()) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});

function validate() {
  var val1 = $('#test').val();
  var val2 = $('#test2').val();
  var val3 = $('#test3').val();

  var valid =
    (val1 !== '' && val3 !== '' && val2 === '') ||
    (val1 === '' && val2 !== '' && val3 !== '');
    
  if (valid) {
    $('.alert.alert-error').hide();
  } else {
    $('.alert.alert-error').show();
  }
  return valid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I corrected the method according to your feedback this did not fix the issue. and please notice that I also updated the question

Comment: @dolly_do updated answer to show how the div classes should be. Now please describe what and when you want to happen. I understand you want on load to hide the alert, when should it be shown or re-hidden ?

Comment: I have updated the question. as you may read the alert should be hidden on document load. but once user submit the form, the alert should be visible in case of invalid input

Comment: @dolly_do just posted an update with many fixes on your code. For more help you will need to post all the relevant html and also please read jquery documentation if you want to use it.

Comment: I see your point, my lack of understanding how javascript/JQuery confused me. I updated the question, so now you can see more clear how I build up my code